# CNN has good loss while training, but bad loss when I test on that same training data

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

So I have a sort of AlexNet CNN for regression. When I train it, the training loss is great, but then the loss for my test images is bad. I thought it was simple overfitting, but then when I test the trained model on the *train images*, I get an equally bad loss even though it is the images it trained on. Maybe I'm mistaken, but shouldn't the loss when predicting on train images be the same as the loss when the model finished? One curious bit of information is that the outputs are all very close to each other.

[image]

Here are two possible culprits:

- I added a ModelCheckpoint callback to save the best epoch weights as a .ckpt file. and call it back at the end of training. I was having some issues with loading it before, but I am not getting any actual errors for it at the moment.
- I have imbalanced data so I recently added class_weights. Although it is regression, all the outputs for training are 0-10 in increments of 0.5, so I can create 20 class weights.

Here is my code for training and testing, and then the code for testing the ckpt model again is below.

```python
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin'

from tensorflow import keras
import keras.backend as K
from keras.utils import plot_model
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = np.load("dataset.npy", allow_pickle=True)

train_images = train_images / 255
test_images = test_images / 255

train_labels = list(map(float, train_labels))
test_labels = list(map(float, test_labels))
train_labels = [i/10 for i in train_labels]
test_labels = [i/10 for i in test_labels]

start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=96, kernel_size=(11, 11), strides=(4, 4), activation='relu', input_shape=(128, 128, 3), padding='same'),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(11, 11), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),
    keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),
    keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),
    keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

plot_model(model, to_file='model.png')

class_weights = {.05: 93.0,
                .10: 31.0,
                .15: 93.0,
                .20: 18.6,
                .25: 46.5,
                .30: 4.894736842105263,
                .35: 7.75,
                .40: 4.043478260869565,
                .45: 2.90625,
                .50: 2.2142857142857144,
                .55: 2.066666666666667,
                .60: 1.5,
                .65: 1.453125,
                .70: 1.0,
                .75: 1.273972602739726,
                .80: 1.6607142857142858,
                .85: 3.72,
                .90: 6.642857142857143,
                .95: 15.5,
                1.0: 1}

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(0.01),
              metrics=['mean_squared_error'],
              weighted_metrics=['mean_squared_error'])

train_images = train_images.reshape(462, 128, 128, 3)
test_images = test_images.reshape(116, 128, 128, 3)

history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=200, callbacks=[keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("./model.ckpt", monitor='mean_squared_error', save_best_only=True, verbose=1)], class_weight=class_weights)

# Plot training & validation loss values
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.title('Model loss')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train', 'Test'], loc='upper left')
plt.ylim(0, 0.5)
plt.show()

model.load_weights("./model.ckpt")

predictions = model.predict(test_images)

totalDifference = 0
for i in range(116):
    print("%s: %s" % (test_labels[i] * 10, predictions[i] * 10))
    totalDifference += abs(test_labels[i] - predictions[i])

avgDifference = totalDifference / 11.6

print("\n%s\n" % avgDifference)
print("Time Elapsed:")
print(datetime.datetime.now() - start_time)
```

Testing by loading the weights through a .ckpt file.

```python
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin'

from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = np.load("dataset.npy", allow_pickle=True)

train_images = train_images / 255
test_images = test_images / 255

train_labels = list(map(float, train_labels))
test_labels = list(map(float, test_labels))
train_labels = [i/10 for i in train_labels]
test_labels = [i/10 for i in test_labels]

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=96, kernel_size=(11, 11), strides=(4, 4), activation='relu', input_shape=(128, 128, 3), padding='same'),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(11, 11), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),
    keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),
    keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),
    keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(0.01),
              metrics=['mean_squared_error'],
              weighted_metrics=['mean_squared_error'])

train_images = train_images.reshape(462, 128, 128, 3)
test_images = test_images.reshape(116, 128, 128, 3)

model.load_weights("./model.ckpt")

train_pred = model.predict(train_images)
totalDifference = 0
for i in range(116):
    print("%s: %s" % (train_labels[i] * 10, train_pred[i] * 10))
    totalDifference += abs(train_labels[i] - train_pred[i])

avgDifference = totalDifference / 11.6
print("\n%s\n" % avgDifference)


predictions = model.predict(test_images)
totalDifference = 0
for i in range(116):
    print("%s: %s" % (test_labels[i] * 10, predictions[i] * 10))
    totalDifference += abs(test_labels[i] - predictions[i])

avgDifference = totalDifference / 11.6
print("\n%s\n" % avgDifference)
```

Any ideas are helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this but on the line

```
history = model.fit(train_images, 
                    train_labels, 
                    epochs=200, 
                    callbacks=[keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("./model.ckpt", monitor='mean_squared_error', save_best_only=True, verbose=1)], 
                    class_weight=class_weights)
```

You might be saving the model with Maximum mean squared error, so pass `mode=min` as an argument to make sure that the model with minimum mean_squared_error is being saved at the end.